# Rails User.all bug found in Hartl's scaffold app - Why is User.all not responding to command like an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scaffold

I discovered this bug while reproducing Michael Hartl's scaffolded rails demo_app from his rails tutorial.

I went into the rails console

**rails c**

I asked for the *User.all* array of hashes and out it through its paces:

2.0.0-p0 :012 > **User.all**

```
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
 => [#<User id: 2, name: "Lisa Johnson", email: "ljohnson@yahoo.com", created_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06", updated_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06">]
```

2.0.0-p0 :013 > **User.all[0]**

```
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
 => #<User id: 2, name: "Lisa Johnson", email: "ljohnson@yahoo.com", created_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06", updated_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06">
```

2.0.0-p0 :015 > **User.all[0]['id']**

```
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
 => 2
```

So far, so good.

However, User.all does not respond to the command to list say just the id's or names of all users:

2.0.0-p0 :017 > **User.all { |i| puts i['id'] }**

```
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
 => [#<User id: 2, name: "Lisa Johnson", email: "ljohnson@yahoo.com", created_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06", updated_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06"gt;]
```

2.0.0-p0 :019 >**User.all{ |i| puts i['name'] }**

```
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
 => [#<User id: 2, name: "Lisa Johnson", email: "ljohnson@yahoo.com", created_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06", updated_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06">]
```

Assigning an arbitrary variable *a* to the array of hashes User.all resolves the issue:

2.0.0-p0 :021 >**a.each {|i| puts i['id'] }**

```
2
 => [#<User id: 2, name: "Lisa Johnson", email: "ljohnson@yahoo.com", created_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06", updated_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06">]
```

2.0.0-p0 :022 >**a.each {|i| puts i['name'] }**

```
Lisa Johnson
 => [#<User id: 2, name: "Lisa Johnson", email: "ljohnson@yahoo.com", created_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06", updated_at: "2013-04-02 03:30:06">]
```

This *User.all* issue affects at least ruby versions 1.9.2,1.9.3 and 2.0.0. Whoever is responsible for writing the gem that created *User.all* needs to go over his **all**  method. For whatever it's worth, I am working with rails 3.2.12

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to discuss - its a straightforward bug report. If there is a question, the question would be "why is **User.all** is not behaving like the array of hashes it is?"